# Switch between Master-Detail View and other view controllers on rotation?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

I am now testing an app for Ipad. Basically I am using template for master detail application and have another portraitViewController. Now when application starts in portrait mode I want it to display only portraitViewController and when device is rotated e.g landscape mode I want to display only master-detailViewController. What is the best way to do this.

I was testing sample code for single view application but master-detail view refuses to hide:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)
interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        self.view = self.portrait;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform =
        CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(0));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        self.view = self.landscape;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform =
        CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(−90));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 300.0);
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation ==
             UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        self.view = self.landscape;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform =
        CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(90));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 300.0);
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view controller should not be changing its view in real time like this. You're not seeing anything happening because the view controller's old view is still in the interface; you're not removing it from the interface. Nor should you do so. The way to make that happen is to swap out the *view controller*; use a different view controller and a different view.

You started with the master-detail view controller, so the app's root view controller is the UISplitViewController. It's view (the split view), it appears, is the view you want to remove. So you will have to replace the UISplitViewController as the window's `rootViewController`.

But that's a huge pain in the butt. I think you might be happier just putting a modal (presented) view controller in front of everything when in portrait orientation.

This is a downloadable example project that presents a view controller in response to device rotation:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/ch19p609rotationForcingModalView

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you suggest any tutorials for modal view controllers.

Comment: You might want to see http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_presented_view_controller (and indeed the whole chapter, maybe).